# Update partial fragment in viewpager android

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have this problem,

in my app there is a viewpager with 3 page, in the middle page (position 1) I have set getPageWidth 0.80f then the page 1 is composed by fragment1 + 0.20 of fragment2
when I scroll to right , from page 0 to page 1 , in this page, the fragment2 refresh after fragment1.

I adopted notifyDataSetChanged(), requestLayout() and I saw this answer :

[ViewPager + PagerAdapter shows blank pages after first two items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659493/viewpager-pageradapter-shows-blank-pages-after-first-two-items)

but I don't resolve my problem.

The question is: how i force update the partial page2 in the viewpager in the same time when update the page1?

Thanks all

Comment: You describe your behavior and describe what you've tried but I fail to see the real question

Comment: Sorry, I have update now the post.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right, but have you tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view/7287121#7287121 ? This will cause that your fragments will not be cached and everytime you swipe, a fragment will be recreated.

Comment: yes, I have already seen this solution, but for me the problem is in the call of requestlayout o ondraw or onmeasure in the viewpager :( I want force that viewpager refreshes both fragment 1 and partial of fragment 2.